# Is Chrome's popup blocker working at all?

Tags: google-chrome, popups

Windows 7, Chrome 11.0.696.71

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html (popup link is about 1 page down)
http://www.buywebsitetrafficnow.com/Popunder-Demo.aspx

I've definitely got the popup blocker set to:
**Do not allow any site to show pop-ups (recommended)**
in chrome://settings/content

Chrome seems to ignore it completely and just pop stuff up.

Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: And yes I know I can install an extension, but why is the native functionality not working...

Comment: Have you tried them in other browsers and confirmed that they are blocked in those?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both sites linked only trigger a popup when you click on a link provided.  Chrome, Firefox, and most other browsers do not block popups triggered by clicking on a link.  If they did, many web applications would break.

I think you'll find that popups triggered without clicking on links are still blocked.  The aptly named [popuptest.com](http://popuptest.com/) will allow you to verify this.

Comment: ok... You're right, but this doesn't seem to tie in with the page in Chrome's launch comic: http://www.google.com/googlebooks/chrome/small_22.html -- "Javascript has no way to force a pop-up into your world"... :( I don't use any of the web applications which need this functionality...

Comment: @Chris:  That comic also claims their autocomplete feature isn't annoying.  I find it highly annoying.  -_-  At any rate, there's an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nmpeeekfhbmikbdhlpjbfmnpgcbeggic) that will block those popups also.

Comment: Thanks for that answer - saved me from "asking" ;-) I got and ad popup at megaupload.com and was wondering how it could happen - exactly the scenario described when clicking on a link.

Comment: “If they did, many web applications would break.” Such Web applications *are already broken*.